# How to subclass in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, subclass

I'd like to subclass QListWidgetItem, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I subclassed QListWidget without any trouble using the same principles.

This is my header file :

```
#ifndef LSPROLISTITEM_H
#define LSPROLISTITEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

class LsproListItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LsproListItem(QString &text, QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
public slots:
};

#endif // LSPROLISTITEM_H
```

and this is my cpp file :

```
#include "lsprolistitem.h"
#include <QListWidgetItem>

LsproListItem::LsproListItem(QString & text, QObject *parent) :
    QListWidgetItem(text, parent)
{
}
```

I don't get the argument from my custom constructor, to create an object based on QListWidgetItem..
I try to create is this way :

```
LsproListItem *simpleText = new LsproListItem("Lorem ipsum");
```

But this fails with :

```
appcms.cpp: error : no matching constructor for initialization of 'LsproListItem'
    LsproListItem *simpleText = new LsproListItem("Lorem ipsum");
                                    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

lsprolistitem.h:7: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [12]' to 'const LsproListItem' for 1st argument
class LsproListItem : public QListWidgetItem
      ^
lsprolistitem.h:: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [12]' to 'QString &' for 1st argument
    explicit LsproListItem(QString &text, QObject *parent = 0);
             ^
```

Comment: It tells you right here: `no known conversion from 'const char [12]' to 'QString &'`. Take const references for parameters, they exist for a reason.

Comment: But when I remove the & from 'text' in my h and cpp, I get errors coming from moc_lsprolistitem.cpp

Comment: Easy, use const everywhere you can. That is, if you never change something, it's a const.

Comment: And here it's even easier, you know QListWidgetItem takes a const reference, you have no reason to change that.

Comment: Well, in that case, I don't get what's wrong with my code? I use constants..

Comment: Why remove it? You need a const reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick solution(not the best): don't use reference:

```
public:
    explicit LsproListItem(QString text, QObject *parent = 0);
    //...
    LsproListItem::LsproListItem(QString text, QObject *parent) :
```

Or

```
public:
    explicit LsproListItem( const QString &text, QObject *parent = 0);
    //...
    LsproListItem::LsproListItem( const QString &text, QObject *parent) :
```

But there is another mistake. Remove `Q_OBJECT` macro because `QListWidgetItem` is not a `QObject` subclass and you can't use here signal and slots.

To prove: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html

Comment: When I do this (your second method) I get thons of errors from a file called moc_lsprolistitem.cpp like this : moc_lsprolistitem.cpp:63: error : no member named 'staticMetaObject' in 'QListWidgetItem'; did you mean simply 'staticMetaObject'?
    { &QListWidgetItem::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_LsproListItem.data,
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       staticMetaObject

Comment: I tried, thanks for you help, but now I get a very weird (non locking) error : lsprolistitem.h:0: error : Note: No relevant classes found. No output generated.

Comment: @VincentDuprez http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/19122-Warning-No-relevant-classes-found rerun qmake also try(make clean; qmake;make)